# Show Success Message After form submit in wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress

How Show Success Message After form submit in word press dashboard?
This code is used for mail sending in word press dashboard.Mail is successfully sending but i need to show success message after sending a mail
please help..My code is

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $val->id; ?>" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Reply to <?php echo $val->mail; ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <form method="POST" action="" >
         <textarea style="  width:  100%; height: 155px;" name="message_content"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="message_id" value="<?php echo $val->id; ?>" >
     <input type="hidden" name="mail_to" value="<?php echo $val->mail; ?>" >
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="send_mail" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </form>   
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['send_mail'])){
$headers=array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  $message=$_POST['message_content'];
  $id=$_POST['message_id'];
  $mail_to=$_POST['mail_to'];
  echo "$message";
  $message_info = wp_mail($mail_to, "hai", $message, $headers);
            }
}
 ?>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried like

```
if($message_info ){
    echo 'Email sent successfully';
}
```

this will display notification if the mail is successfully sent